Reverse running total SQL
I'm trying to use SQL in Bigquery to calculate the running total.
This is what my code currently outputs:

However, I want the running total to start from the earliest date:

Here's my current SQL code:
WITH recruits AS (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC(startdate, MONTH) AS month_start,
         COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeID) AS recruits_count
  FROM EmployeeTable
  GROUP BY month_start
),
exits AS (
  SELECT DATE_TRUNC(TerminatedDate, MONTH) AS month_terminated,
         COUNT(DISTINCT EmployeeID) AS exits_count
  FROM EmployeeTable
  GROUP BY month_terminated
)
SELECT COALESCE(recruits.month_start, exits.month_terminated) AS month,
       COALESCE(recruits.recruits_count, 0) AS recruits,
       COALESCE(exits.exits_count, 0) AS exits,
       COALESCE(recruits.recruits_count, 0) - COALESCE(exits.exits_count, 0),
       SUM(COALESCE(recruits.recruits_count, 0) - COALESCE(exits.exits_count, 0))
           OVER (ORDER BY COALESCE(recruits.month_start, exits.month_terminated) ASC) AS running_total
FROM exits
FULL OUTER JOIN recruits ON recruits.month_start = exits.month_terminated 

What am I doing wrong? :( Would love to learn from you guys, because I'm stuck.
Thank you!
I've tried the following to the running total from the EARLIEST date, such as:

Changing ASC to DESC (for the running total function)
Switching recruits.month_start, exits.month_terminated to exits.month_terminated, recruits.month_start (for the running total function).

But I can't seem to make it work :( What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this?
